# How can I know that a third party docker image get access to our upload data to container

Tags: docker, annotations, docker-image, data-security

I downloaded a docker image from a third party. It's an annotation tool.
To use I need to run that image, sign up and upload my data to annotate.
Although it can be run without internet.
Problem is I can't understanding whether the image provider get access to my data or not.
Is there any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Check the network connection of the container for heartbeat or C&C.

2.Check that the upper layer of the mirror is reliable, and if so, just make sure that the additions are safe.

Comment: Hi @johnny thank you so much. I will follow your instruction.